# How to make "xinput --set-prop 11 "Synaptics Finger" 10 15 100" permanent?

Tags: touchpad, startup, xinput

Title says it all, every time I shut down I have to rerun `xinput --set-prop 11 "Synaptics Finger" 10 15 100` again is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue.  As an alternative to Humpity's answer, I just made a shell script saved in my home directory then added it to my `Startup Applications` list.

"Startup script.sh":

```
#!/bin/bash
xinput set-prop "appletouch" "Synaptics Finger" 10, 20, 100
```

Then open the `Startup Applications` GUI (which should be installed by default in ubuntu) and add a new entry to the list with the command field like so:

```
"/home/user_name/Startup script.sh"
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a command inside a .desktop file

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=USER autostart
Comment=my commands after X startup
Exec=<your command>
```

And save it as [your-home]/.config/autostart/user-autostart.desktop
This will execute when X starts.