# executing xinput from a script in sleep.d

Tags: 14.04, mouse, suspend, xinput

My mouse was too fast for my taste so I decreased its speed using a xinput command :

```
xinput set-prop $id "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 2.5
```

I put the command in `~/.profile` so that it executes on startup. At startup, it always works.

My problem is that **the setting seems to be reset when my computer resumes after standby**. Not always, maybe half the time.

I tried to put the command in a script in `/etc/pm/sleep.d/`, and it was executed but for some reason didn't work.

Any ideas ? Answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530762/how-to-make-xinput-set-prop-11-synaptics-finger-10-15-100-permanent) suggests xinput commands should go in a `.desktop` file : would that change anything ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got it to work ! It appears running `xinput` from a `sleep.d` script requires some tweaks. Here is what I did. Hope it will be of some use to someone.

So I have one script called `40mouse_slow` I put in `/etc/pm/sleep.d`. The `40` is used for ordering. On resume, low numbers start *last*. User scripts should use `00` to `49`. Make sure the script has execution rights. Here is the script :

```
#!/bin/sh
case "$1" in
    resume|thaw)
        /home/yannick/scripts/mouse_slow.sh &
    ;;
    *)
        # Nothing.
    ;;
esac
```

It only says the script `/home/yannick/scripts/mouse_slow.sh` should be launched *in the background* when computer resumes. I tried launching it not in background, but that broke resuming (network didn't work, for example).

Here is `/home/yannick/scripts/mouse_slow.sh`. Also make sure it has execution rights :

```
#!/bin/sh
export DISPLAY=:0.0
id=`su yannick -c "xinput" | grep 'PID:400a' | cut -c58-60`
su yannick -c "xinput set-prop $id 'Device Accel Constant Deceleration' 2.5"
```

The second line is just to find the id of my mouse. As for the two other lines, they ilustrate the two things I found had to be done to make `xinput` work when it is called from a script in `sleep.d` :

- `DISPLAY` must be set and exported
- the user executing `xinput` must be the user running X, not root.