# Touchpad stopped working after suspend/sleep

Tags: 20.04, suspend, touchpad, thinkpad

Installed Ubuntu 20.04 early this week but i'm still struggling to make my touchpad working after waking up from suspend.

I can confirmed that, touchpad will work again after it's completely shutdown (reboot won't work).

Weirdly, touchpad is working back again when i try to reboot (while the touchpad not working) and go into bios then boot into ubuntu after that (no shutdown at all).

But with hibernate, touchpad is working fine after waking up but i really didn't have much time to wait for hibernation processing time.. it's way longer than suspending.

In windows, the touchpad was working fine though.. seems this is related to the linux driver.

I've tried with other people suggestions like
[Touchpad stopped working 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1235067/touchpad-stopped-working-20-04)
and bunch others i could find from reddit but none of them working.

Really appreciate if i could get touchpad and sleep mode working together just like hibernate did.

Here are some details from the T480:

`lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #7 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1d.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #11 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point LPC Controller/eSPI Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (4) I219-LM (rev 21)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX150] (rev a1)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)
04:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6240 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (Low Power) [Alpine Ridge LP 2016] (rev 01)
05:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6240 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (Low Power) [Alpine Ridge LP 2016] (rev 01)
05:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6240 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (Low Power) [Alpine Ridge LP 2016] (rev 01)
05:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6240 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (Low Power) [Alpine Ridge LP 2016] (rev 01)
06:00.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation JHL6240 Thunderbolt 3 NHI (Low Power) [Alpine Ridge LP 2016] (rev 01)
3c:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation JHL6240 Thunderbolt 3 USB 3.1 Controller (Low Power) [Alpine Ridge LP 2016] (rev 01)
3d:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Toshiba Corporation Device 0116
```

`lsusb`

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0316 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB3.0-CRW
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 06cb:009a Synaptics, Inc.
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b604 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated Camera (1280x720@30)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b613 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated IR Camera
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 2a94:464d G2Touch Multi-Touch by G2TSP
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`xinput`

```
Virtual core pointer                     id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                 id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ G2Touch Multi-Touch by G2TSP               id=10    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                 id=14    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                      id=15    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                      id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard                id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                               id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus                                  id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus                                  id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Sleep Button                               id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Integrated IR Camera: Integrate            id=11    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C            id=12    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard               id=13    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                     id=16    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

`cat /proc/bus/input/devices`

```
 I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0003 Version=0000
 N: Name="Sleep Button"
 P: Phys=PNP0C0E/button/input0
 S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input0
 U: Uniq=
 H: Handlers=kbd event0
 B: PROP=0
 B: EV=3
 B: KEY=4000 0 0
 
 I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0005 Version=0000
 N: Name="Lid Switch"
 P: Phys=PNP0C0D/button/input0
 S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input1
 U: Uniq=
 H: Handlers=event1
 B: PROP=0
 B: EV=21
 B: SW=1
 
 I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000
 N: Name="Power Button"
 P: Phys=LNXPWRBN/button/input0
 S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2
 U: Uniq=
 H: Handlers=kbd event2
 B: PROP=0
 B: EV=3
 B: KEY=10000000000000 0
 
 I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=ab54
 N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
 P: Phys=isa0060/serio0/input0
 S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3
 U: Uniq=
 H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event3 leds
 B: PROP=0
 B: EV=120013
 B: KEY=402000000 3803078f800d001 feffffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
 B: MSC=10
 B: LED=7
 
 I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=0007 Version=01b1
 N: Name="SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
 P: Phys=isa0060/serio1/input0
 S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5
 U: Uniq=
 H: Handlers=mouse0 event4
 B: PROP=5
 B: EV=b
 B: KEY=e520 10000 0 0 0 0
 B: ABS=660800011000003
 
 I: Bus=0019 Vendor=17aa Product=5054 Version=4101
 N: Name="ThinkPad Extra Buttons"
 P: Phys=thinkpad_acpi/input0
 S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/input/input7
 U: Uniq=
 H: Handlers=rfkill kbd event5
 B: PROP=0
 B: EV=33
 B: KEY=10040 0 18040000 0 50000000000000 0 1701b02102004 c000280051115000 10e000000000000 0
 B: MSC=10
 B: SW=8
 
 I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=000a Version=0000
 N: Name="TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint"
 P: Phys=synaptics-pt/serio0/input0
 S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/serio2/input/input6
 U: Uniq=
 H: Handlers=mouse1 event6
 B: PROP=21
 B: EV=7
 B: KEY=70000 0 0 0 0
 B: REL=3
 
 I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0006 Version=0000
 N: Name="Video Bus"
 P: Phys=LNXVIDEO/video/input0
 S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input8
 U: Uniq=
 H: Handlers=kbd event7
 B: PROP=0
 B: EV=3
 B: KEY=3e000b00000000 0 0 0
 
 I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0006 Version=0000
 N: Name="Video Bus"
 P: Phys=LNXVIDEO/video/input0
 S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:35/LNXVIDEO:01/input/input9
 U: Uniq=
 H: Handlers=kbd event8
 B: PROP=0
 B: EV=3
 B: KEY=3e000b00000000 0 0 0
 
 I: Bus=0003 Vendor=04f2 Product=b613 Version=0005
 N: Name="Integrated IR Camera: Integrate"
 P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-5/button
 S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/input/input10
 U: Uniq=
 H: Handlers=kbd event9
 B: PROP=0
 B: EV=3
 B: KEY=100000 0 0 0
 
 I: Bus=0003 Vendor=04f2 Product=b604 Version=0027
 N: Name="Integrated Camera: Integrated C"
 P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-8/button
 S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/input/input13
 U: Uniq=
 H: Handlers=kbd event10
 B: PROP=0
 B: EV=3
 B: KEY=100000 0 0 0
 
 I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
 N: Name="HDA Intel PCH Mic"
 P: Phys=ALSA
 S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input11
 U: Uniq=
 H: Handlers=event11
 B: PROP=0
 B: EV=21
 B: SW=10
 
 I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
 N: Name="HDA Intel PCH Headphone"
 P: Phys=ALSA
 S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input12
 U: Uniq=
 H: Handlers=event12
 B: PROP=0
 B: EV=21
 B: SW=4
 
 I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
 N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3"
 P: Phys=ALSA
 S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input14
 U: Uniq=
 H: Handlers=event13
 B: PROP=0
 B: EV=21
 B: SW=140
 
 I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
 N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7"
 P: Phys=ALSA
 S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input15
 U: Uniq=
 H: Handlers=event14
 B: PROP=0
 B: EV=21
 B: SW=140
 
 I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
 N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8"
 P: Phys=ALSA
 S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input16
 U: Uniq=
 H: Handlers=event15
 B: PROP=0
 B: EV=21
 B: SW=140
 
 I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
 N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9"
 P: Phys=ALSA
 S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input17
 U: Uniq=
 H: Handlers=event16
 B: PROP=0
 B: EV=21
 B: SW=140
 
 I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
 N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10"
 P: Phys=ALSA
 S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input18
 U: Uniq=
 H: Handlers=event17
 B: PROP=0
 B: EV=21
 B: SW=140
 
 I: Bus=0003 Vendor=2a94 Product=464d Version=0111
 N: Name="G2Touch Multi-Touch by G2TSP"
 P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-10/input0
 S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-10/1-10:1.0/0003:2A94:464D.0001/input/input20
 U: Uniq=
 H: Handlers=mouse2 event18
 B: PROP=2
 B: EV=1b
 B: KEY=400 0 0 0 0 0
 B: ABS=260800000000003
 B: MSC=20
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on my Lenovo laptop with kubuntu 22.04. After suspend / hibernate the touchpad was turned off.

What worked for me was disabling and enabling the xinput;

```sh
xinput disable 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad' && xinput enable 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad'
```

(I got your touchpad from the output of `xinput list`)

If this restarts your touchpad you can add the command in a script get it executed automatically after sleep; this answer helped me to get such a script working [executing xinput from a script in sleep.d](https://askubuntu.com/questions/682796/executing-xinput-from-a-script-in-sleep-d)

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks ! a variant worked for me :
1) find the name of the faulty device `xinput list`
2) adapt the command `xinput disable '<name>' && xinput enable '<name>'`

Answer (score 1):

The above didnt work for me (I have a thinkpad l440). If you look in dmesg you will probably see some rmi errors (looks like a kernel bug with IRQ reading).

Do this to fix the touchpad after resume:

```
rmmod rmi_smbus && modprobe rmi_smbus
```

Make yourself a systemctl service to automate this fix:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run command on resume
After=suspend.target

[Service]
User=root
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "rmmod rmi_smbus && modprobe rmi_smbus"

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The manual steps worked well on my old Macbook Pro 2015, running Fedora Silverblue F39 and thus Wayland instead of X11. Used `sudo dmesg` to find that the kernel module driver [bcm5974](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/input/devices/bcm5974.html) repeatedly reported `bcm5974: bad trackpad package, length: 8`. Running `sudo rmmod bcm5974 && sudo modprobe bcm5974` fixed it right away. Thanks!