# Touchpad not re-enable reversing screen or after close lid

Tags: touchpad, lenovo

I have a Lenovo IdeaPad Flex 5
with Ubuntu 22.10.

When I revert the screen to use in tabled mode everything is working fine: physical keyboard gets disable and virtual appear and touchped get disable too.

When I turn back in the normal way, touchpad is not re-enable.

The same happens when I close the laptop: it disables the touchpad but when I reopen screen it is still disabled.

I need to use touchscreen to open the setting and enable it back.

I collected this information

> cat /proc/bus/input/devices I: Bus=0018 Vendor=06cb Product=ce2d
> Version=0100 N: Name="MSFT0001:00 06CB:CE2D Mouse" P:
> Phys=i2c-MSFT0001:00 S:
> Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/i2c_designware.0/i2c-1/i2c-MSFT0001:00/0018:06CB:CE2D.0001/input/input15
> U: Uniq= H: Handlers=mouse0 event4  B: PROP=0 B: EV=17 B: KEY=30000 0
> 0 0 0 B: REL=3 B: MSC=10
>
> I: Bus=0018 Vendor=06cb Product=ce2d Version=0100 N: Name="MSFT0001:00
> 06CB:CE2D Touchpad" P: Phys=i2c-MSFT0001:00 S:
> Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/i2c_designware.0/i2c-1/i2c-MSFT0001:00/0018:06CB:CE2D.0001/input/input16
> U: Uniq= H: Handlers=mouse1 event7  B: PROP=5 B: EV=1b B: KEY=e520
> 10000 0 0 0 0 B: ABS=2e0800000000003 B: MSC=20

Any hints?

Comment: Can you please tell us what the model of the Lenovo ideaPad is? Also, it would be useful if you could also provide us with the touchpad device hardware information (the `cat /proc/bus/input/devices` command should provide vendor:product:version info).

Comment: @richbl edited the post

Comment: have you tried [this?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332972/touchpad-stopped-working-after-suspend-sleep)