# How to write a script and have it run on Ubuntu 16.04 boot

Tags: boot, command-line, scripts, mouse-scroll, magic-mouse

I have figured out how to use Terminal to change my Apple Magic Mouse settings to be how I like them. I am using the following lines of code.

remove mouse module settings

```
$ sudo rmmod hid_magicmouse
```

add faster scrolling settings

```
e$ sudo modprobe hid_magicmouse emulate_3button=0 scroll_acceleration=1 scroll_speed=55
```

reverse scroll direction

```
xinput set-button-map 14 1 2 3 5 4
```

When I restart the computer, all these setting are lost and I have to re-input them into terminal.

How do I create a script, and where do I save it so that it will run every time I boot the computer.

I am a complete novice in Ubuntu so I don't even know what file extension to use. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: IMHO it would be better to create a suitable `/etc/modprobe.d/hid_magicmouse.conf` file as described here [How to set the scroll speed of apple magic mouse?](http://askubuntu.com/a/262730/178692), and then run your `xinput` command via Startup Applications as described [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/665200/178692)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a script so that it will run the commands by a single execution of that script, you need to create a file with '.sh' extension.

Open the terminal, and in a suitable directory, create a script file.

```
    $vi <name you prefer>.sh
```

This is will open the VI editor. Or you can choose any other editor if you prefer. 
Then add each command in a new line, and then save the file.
Your file should look something like

```
    #!/bin/sh
    sudo rmmod hid_magicmouse
    sudo modprobe hid_magicmouse emulate_3button=0 scroll_acceleration=1 scroll_speed=55
    xinput set-button-map 14 1 2 3 5 4
```

Now set the executable permissions to this file,

```
    $chmod +x <nameoffile>.sh
```

And now execute the file,

```
    $sudo ./<nameoffile>.sh
```

Execute the file with `sudo` permissions as your commands need to executed as superuser. Your mouse settings should have taken their place.

To run the script at boot, you can check the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228304/how-do-i-run-a-script-at-start-up).

Comment: hi thanks for your help! I am able to have the sh file run when I manually type in the file name in Terminal. When I go to edit the /etc/rc.local file I type in the command /home/jono/Documents/scripts/magicMouseFix.sh || exit 1 and when I hit return I get an error stating "pattern not found: home" I am stuck at this point... not sure what to do next

Comment: Okay turns out I had to learn how to properly use the vim editor. thanks so much for your answer. I can now restart my computer and the mouse settings are correct.

Comment: You're welcome ! @JTMKoenig